# Call PowerShell script with argument from another Powershell script with bypass

Tags: powershell

I need to call a ps1 Script during going through another ps1 file. The new call shouldn't interrupt the script which I'm going through. Also I always call the Powershell scripts like this: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File file.ps1 -param log_14.txt` due to execution policies.

I tried following code in my .ps1 script, sadly it doesn't work:

```
    Start-Job PowerShell -Argument "sort.ps1 -file $fileName"
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: So it means you need to pass a parameter to a ps1 script within a job?

Comment: @WasifHasan yes i need to call a FIle with a Parameter in my File which I'm gooing through

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "filepath.ps1 Param"
}
$job | wait-job | receive-job
```

Comment: `The argument 'sort.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an
argument to the -File parameter.` This is what i get

Comment: You need to give  the full file path!